# React native 0.73.5 sdk 34 build error : One of RECIEVER_EXPORTED or RECIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-firebase

[image]

i upgrade my rn from 0.68 to 0.73.5 to use android 14
i had many problems and build error,at the end i get build successfull but when i want build on sdk34
this error appear on screen and its not specific error to handle that
it shows after splash screen and by clicking DISMISS i can run the app but sometimes its crash with no error or log that i guess its refers to this problem
i searched github and stack,others have problem with share system , ... that not relate to my error